# Very Slow loading. Plugins report provided by P3 included

Tags: plugins, performance

My problem perhaps has to be with the plugin I'm using. However I wanted to be sure if something else could be causing the problem.

I'm retrieving two feeds using WP RSS multi-importer plugin, but that page's loading time is increibly slow.

feed 1: `http://www.paho.org/arg/index.php?format=feed&type=rss`

feed 2: `http://feeds.feedburner.com/diariosalud/tVxp?format=xml`

which are loaded instantly in simplepie.org/demo

This is my page hosted -> http://bit.ly/fdp-rssimporter

and these are my results of P3, running only that page twice:

```
WordPress Plugin Profile Report
===========================================
Report date: 9 junio, 2014
Theme name: Openstrap
Pages browsed: 2
Avg. load time: 7.9207 sec
Number of plugins: 12
Plugin impact: 89.26% of load time
Avg. plugin time: 7.0697 sec
Avg. core time: 0.6246 sec
Avg. theme time: 0.1077 sec
Avg. mem usage: 91.25 MB
Avg. ticks: 88,235
Avg. db queries : 66.50
Margin of error : 0.1186 sec

Plugin list:
===========================================
P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler) - 0.0181 sec - 0.26%
iThemes Security - 0.3094 sec - 4.38%
Bstw - 0.0113 sec - 0.16%
Duplicator - 0.0166 sec - 0.23%
Jetpack por WordPress.com - 1.5392 sec - 21.77%
Lightbox - 0.6302 sec - 8.91%
Meta Slider - 0.0917 sec - 1.30%
Post Expirator - 0.0053 sec - 0.07%
TinyMCE Advanced - 0.0088 sec - 0.12%
Types - 0.2622 sec - 3.71%
RSS Multi Importer - 3.9929 sec - 56.48%
Wysija Newsletters - 0.1840 sec - 2.60%
```

Comment: Seems pretty cut and dried to me.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You should contact the author of the plugin/theme about this problem